# Is react-navigation incompatible with react-native 0.57?

Tags: android, react-native

i'm new to react-native, npm, etc ..
But I can follow some samples an run some test of a android app.

Now I want to learn navigation. 
I follow steps in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation ...

But after I install react-navigation, I can't use anymore "react-native run-android" command...

```
C:\Users\Nicolas\react-native-app\KleinProject>react-native run-android
Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
```

What is wrong? npm ? react-native ?

I read somewhere that react-navigation work with react-native <=0.51

Mi version are:

SO: Win 10

npm: 6.4.1

react-native: 0.57

How can I use react-navigation, in react-native ?

Best Regards

Comment: Try to delete all stuff out of your node_modules folder and then reinstall everything by typing npm install into your command line at the project level. Than, your React-Native and all packages get reinstalled and your node modules folder will be filled again.

Comment: i am using react-navigation with 0.57, and i have no problems with it.

Answer (score -1):

1. install nodejs
2. install react-native-cli

   > npm i -g react-native-cli
3. create a project using "react-native" <- i think you didn't do this

   > react-native init projectname
4. install react-navigation using

   > cd project/folder
   >
   > npm i react-navigation